# Compiling C++ Program Causes "Fatal Error LNK1104"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I am trying to compile a c++ application using the following command in command prompt:

```
cl -I"c:\Program files\Java\jdk1.5.0_07\include" -I"c:\program files\java\jdk1.5.0_07\include\win32" -MD -LD HelloWorld.cpp -FeHelloWorld.dll
```

However, this produces the following error:

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'

Have you any ideas of what is causing this and how to fix it?

I have visual studio 2005 installed on windows.

Thanks,

-Pete

Comment: What's this 'command prompt' of which you speak?  I just click on the button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
>
> Any ideas of what is causing this and how to fix it?

The linker needs to be pointed to the location of MSVCRT.lib, as it doesn't seem to be in your LIBPATH.

It should be here: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 7\VC\lib**

Add `-link -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\lib"`

Comment: thanks! adding:

-link -LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\lib"

solved it

Answer (score 4):

To Solve this Problem in MS Visual studio 2008.

1. Goto Menu Project->Properties (Alt+F7)
2. Configuration Properties
3. Linker -> General -> additional Library Directories -> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib

....do the above steps and enjoy

Comment: Thanks!, for Visual Studio 2017 the dir is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\lib\x64

Answer (score 1):

In the command prompt run the following command
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

Then work in the same command prompt.