# Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'winmm.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, directx

Ok, so I am running Visual Basic 2010 Express and I tried to run Tutorial # 2 in the Direct X SDK; however, the program won't compile for some reason, although in the tutorial I am reading now it said that I only needed the Direct X SDK and Visual Basic 2010 Express. I opened Tutorial02_2010.sln, and tried to compile it. Here's the code of the main file:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// File: Tutorial02.cpp
//
// This application displays a triangle using Direct3D 10
//
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d10.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include "resource.h"


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Structures
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct SimpleVertex
{
    D3DXVECTOR3 Pos;
};


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Global Variables
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HINSTANCE               g_hInst = NULL;
HWND                    g_hWnd = NULL;
D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE       g_driverType = D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_NULL;
ID3D10Device*           g_pd3dDevice = NULL;
IDXGISwapChain*         g_pSwapChain = NULL;
ID3D10RenderTargetView* g_pRenderTargetView = NULL;
ID3D10Effect*           g_pEffect = NULL;
ID3D10EffectTechnique*  g_pTechnique = NULL;
ID3D10InputLayout*      g_pVertexLayout = NULL;
ID3D10Buffer*           g_pVertexBuffer = NULL;


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declarations
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow );
HRESULT InitDevice();
void CleanupDevice();
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc( HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM );
void Render();


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Entry point to the program. Initializes everything and goes into a message processing 
// loop. Idle time is used to render the scene.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
int WINAPI wWinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow )
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( hPrevInstance );
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( lpCmdLine );

    if( FAILED( InitWindow( hInstance, nCmdShow ) ) )
        return 0;

    if( FAILED( InitDevice() ) )
    {
        CleanupDevice();
        return 0;
    }

    // Main message loop
    MSG msg = {0};
    while( WM_QUIT != msg.message )
    {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else
        {
            Render();
        }
    }

    CleanupDevice();

    return ( int )msg.wParam;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Register class and create window
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitWindow( HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow )
{
    // Register class
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon( hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor( NULL, IDC_ARROW );
    wcex.hbrBackground = ( HBRUSH )( COLOR_WINDOW + 1 );
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = L"TutorialWindowClass";
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon( wcex.hInstance, ( LPCTSTR )IDI_TUTORIAL1 );
    if( !RegisterClassEx( &wcex ) )
        return E_FAIL;

    // Create window
    g_hInst = hInstance;
    RECT rc = { 0, 0, 640, 480 };
    AdjustWindowRect( &rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE );
    g_hWnd = CreateWindow( L"TutorialWindowClass", L"Direct3D 10 Tutorial 2: Rendering a Triangle",
                           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                           CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, hInstance,
                           NULL );
    if( !g_hWnd )
        return E_FAIL;

    ShowWindow( g_hWnd, nCmdShow );

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create Direct3D device and swap chain
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT InitDevice()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect( g_hWnd, &rc );
    UINT width = rc.right - rc.left;
    UINT height = rc.bottom - rc.top;

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
    {
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
    };
    UINT numDriverTypes = sizeof( driverTypes ) / sizeof( driverTypes[0] );

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    ZeroMemory( &sd, sizeof( sd ) );
    sd.BufferCount = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    sd.Windowed = TRUE;

    for( UINT driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex++ )
    {
        g_driverType = driverTypes[driverTypeIndex];
        hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, g_driverType, NULL, createDeviceFlags,
                                            D3D10_SDK_VERSION, &sd, &g_pSwapChain, &g_pd3dDevice );
        if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
            break;
    }
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Create a render target view
    ID3D10Texture2D* pBuffer;
    hr = g_pSwapChain->GetBuffer( 0, __uuidof( ID3D10Texture2D ), ( LPVOID* )&pBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView( pBuffer, NULL, &g_pRenderTargetView );
    pBuffer->Release();
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    g_pd3dDevice->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &g_pRenderTargetView, NULL );

    // Setup the viewport
    D3D10_VIEWPORT vp;
    vp.Width = width;
    vp.Height = height;
    vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    vp.TopLeftX = 0;
    vp.TopLeftY = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );

    // Create the effect
    DWORD dwShaderFlags = D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS;
#if defined( DEBUG ) || defined( _DEBUG )
    // Set the D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG flag to embed debug information in the shaders.
    // Setting this flag improves the shader debugging experience, but still allows 
    // the shaders to be optimized and to run exactly the way they will run in 
    // the release configuration of this program.
    dwShaderFlags |= D3D10_SHADER_DEBUG;
    #endif
    hr = D3DX10CreateEffectFromFile( L"Tutorial02.fx", NULL, NULL, "fx_4_0", dwShaderFlags, 0,
                                         g_pd3dDevice, NULL, NULL, &g_pEffect, NULL, NULL );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    L"The FX file cannot be located.  Please run this executable from the directory that contains the FX file.", L"Error", MB_OK );
        return hr;
    }

    // Obtain the technique
    g_pTechnique = g_pEffect->GetTechniqueByName( "Render" );

    // Define the input layout
    D3D10_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D10_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    UINT numElements = sizeof( layout ) / sizeof( layout[0] );

    // Create the input layout
    D3D10_PASS_DESC PassDesc;
    g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex( 0 )->GetDesc( &PassDesc );
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, PassDesc.pIAInputSignature,
                                          PassDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &g_pVertexLayout );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set the input layout
    g_pd3dDevice->IASetInputLayout( g_pVertexLayout );

    // Create vertex buffer
    SimpleVertex vertices[] =
    {
        D3DXVECTOR3( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f ),
        D3DXVECTOR3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
        D3DXVECTOR3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f ),
    };
    D3D10_BUFFER_DESC bd;
    bd.Usage = D3D10_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 3;
    bd.BindFlags = D3D10_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bd.MiscFlags = 0;
    D3D10_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        return hr;

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
    UINT offset = 0;
    g_pd3dDevice->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

    // Set primitive topology
    g_pd3dDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology( D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST );

    return S_OK;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Clean up the objects we've created
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void CleanupDevice()
{
    if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->ClearState();

    if( g_pVertexBuffer ) g_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if( g_pVertexLayout ) g_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if( g_pEffect ) g_pEffect->Release();
    if( g_pRenderTargetView ) g_pRenderTargetView->Release();
    if( g_pSwapChain ) g_pSwapChain->Release();
    if( g_pd3dDevice ) g_pd3dDevice->Release();
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Called every time the application receives a message
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch( message )
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            EndPaint( hWnd, &ps );
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage( 0 );
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc( hWnd, message, wParam, lParam );
    }

    return 0;
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Render a frame
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Render()
{
    // Clear the back buffer 
    float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.125f, 0.3f, 1.0f }; // red,green,blue,alpha
    g_pd3dDevice->ClearRenderTargetView( g_pRenderTargetView, ClearColor );

    // Render a triangle
    D3D10_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    g_pTechnique->GetDesc( &techDesc );
    for( UINT p = 0; p < techDesc.Passes; ++p )
    {
        g_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex( p )->Apply( 0 );
        g_pd3dDevice->Draw( 3, 0 );
    }

    // Present the information rendered to the back buffer to the front buffer (the screen)
    g_pSwapChain->Present( 0, 0 );
}
```

Do I need to install anything else, like a library or something and do I just need to follow the same steps I had to take for the Direct x lib files?

http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut01.html

Comment: windows sdk .... the express edition you have requires the windows sdk before it can compile windows programs. Make sure after you install the windows sdk, you point the project include and lib paths to also point to the windows sdk install directory.

Comment: do i just have to install it? or do i also have to "link" it?

Comment: Install it. What version of windows are you on? And see my previous comment. You'll have to tell the project your working on where to find the windows SDK. The tutorial you are reading assumes visual studio 2010 professional or above. The windows sdk for windows 7 comes with the professional edition, the express you have to install and set up on your own. Its a free development environment with all the nice bells and whistles of the editor and compiler of visiual studio, minus the sdk.

Comment: Excuse me, but you'll also need visual stuido express C++, not BASIC...

Comment: i am on vista and i installed the windows sdk for vista and it's not working. i got another error. see comment below.

Comment: yeah i am using visual express c++ express... it was a typo

Answer (score 2):

1. Install visual studio Express C++.
2. Install the Windows SDK for windows 7.
3. After recreating a new project for that copy+pasted code, point the project properties to the windows sdk, as well as the direct X sdk. This includes both include folders, and lib folders. If you don't know how to do that, Go check out the "how do i" videos on msdn.com for visual studio 2010.
4. Compile.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D10\Tutorials\Tutorial02\LINK

Comment: i installed the one for windows vista and got this error now. for some reason i only got 1 error, which is strange.

Comment: did you follow all the steps i outline above? Particularly 2 and 3?

Comment: yes, i get Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\Direct3D10\Tutorials\Tutorial00\LINK

Comment: Go to your project properties , select Linker from left.Add this to "Additional Library Directories" : "(Your Visual Studio Path)\VC\lib" For example : C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: it worked.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228112/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-msvcrtd-lib

Answer (score 0):

I got a very similar error with Visual Studio 2013 Express:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'winmm.lib'
```

For me, it turned out I'd installed 'Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows', when I actually needed 'Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop'.

Installing 'Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop' cured the error for me.