# How to know the INCLUDE, LIB, PATH outcome of Visual Studio 2010,2013 Toolset

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Since VS2010, Microsoft Visual Studio introduces the Platform Toolset concept that encapsulate the traditional global INCLUDE, LIB, PATH settings inside various Toolsets. I admit that's an improvement for flexibility, but it should not be a blackbox that makes us foolish.

Now my question is, how do I know what the resulting INCLUDE, LIB, PATH are when I apply a  Toolset to my project. I think it is not realistic to analyze those hundreds of .targets and .props files(in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120`)  manually to get the result. Most of the time, we just need the result. Is there any concise way to achieve that?

[image]

==== UPDATE ====

Stijn provides the right answer for me. Now I can see PATH= , LIB= , INCLUDE= ... from the build log. But, a minor question, what is the difference of `LIB` and `LIBPATH`?

```
1>Using "SetEnv" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  PATH=C:\VS2013\VC\bin;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools;C:\VS2013\Common7\Tools\bin;C:\VS2013\Common7\tools;C:\VS2013\Common7\ide;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;C:\Windows\SysWow64;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;;C:\Windows-Kits\8.1\bin\x86;C:\Windows-Kits\8.1\tools\tracing\x86
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  LIB=C:\VS2013\VC\lib;C:\VS2013\VC\atlmfc\lib;;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  LIBPATH=C:\VS2013\VC\atlmfc\lib;C:\VS2013\VC\lib;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  INCLUDE=D:\u8vc\USBview\C++\;C:\VS2013\VC\include;C:\VS2013\VC\atlmfc\include;;
```

Comment: regarding your update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483619/what-is-the-difference-between-the-lib-and-libpath-environment-variables-for-ms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easisest way is probably to adjust the msbuild log settings so the INCLUDE/LIB/PATH environment variables are printed to the output window. In Visual Studio's options you can either:

- set `Projects and Solutions->VC++ Project Settings->Show Envirohnment In Log` to `Yes`
- set `Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed` or `Diagnostic`

Then in the build log grep for INCLUDE etc

For command line builds use the `/v:d` switch with MSBuild.

Comment: Just typing, say, "set include" in a pre-build event is another easy way to find out.