# After installing WDK VC++ is broken

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, wdk

Installed the WDK from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

Afterwords I can no longer compile any VC++ project. Repairing Visual Studios install doesn't fix the issue.

**System: Windows 10, x64, Visual Studio 2017**

Uninstalling all WDK (Windows Driver Kit) stuff seems to fix the problem but means I can't compile libs that depend on it.

Answer (score 3):

The error list gave me a bit more of a hint on how to solve this.
[image: Spectre mitigation is enabled but Spectre mitigated libraries are not installed]

[image: Editing VS2019 components to install Spectre-mitigated libraries]

After installing the Spectre-mitigated libraries I was able to build my project - MSVCRT.lib was found. There isn't enough info in your initial post to tell whether this is your issue, but if you get this error, it may be that Visual Studio isn't able to find the *particular* runtime that it's looking for.