# VS2022 "lld-link : error : could not open 'oldnames.lib': no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, visual-studio-2022

Just installed Windows 10 and VS2022, created an empty project, set compiler to Clang, compiled and I get these errors:

```
1>lld-link : error : could not open 'msvcrtd.lib': no such file or directory
1>lld-link : error : could not open 'oldnames.lib': no such file or directory
```

I'm sure I could add a path to the linker settings but I don't understand why this error occurs "out of the box"? Is there a bug with the VS2022 installation/surely this should not happen?

Answer (score 0):

For could not open 'msvcrtd.lib', installing the Windos 10 SDK in Visual Studio Installer usually solves the problem. But just in case I also recommend you to read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228112/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-msvcrtd-lib).

[image]

About could not open 'oldnames.lib', you could refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7cf77b51-0868-4a05-92fa-6999c2317ad2/error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-oldnameslib?forum=vseditor) in MSDN.