# VC++ 2010 Express Error: cannot open file MSVCRTD.lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, compiler-errors, installation

I have just uninstalled Visual Studio 2012 in favor of reinstalling Visual C++ 2010 Express. The reason is that I cannot get an API to work with 2012 and I had been using 2010 previously and know it works so I wanted to revert back. So, after reinstalling VC++ 2010 Express and attempting to run a simple Win32 Console App:

```
int main () {

    return 0;

}
```

I get this error: **LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'**

I've done research and am aware of this typically being an issue where I would just need to point the Additional Include Directories to the VC/lib folder in the VC++ root folder [[See this thread]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927574/compiling-c-program-causes-fatal-error-lnk1104) however that lib folder doesn't actually exist. I've attempted to completely uninstall and reinstall the software several times but it yields the same results.

What else can I do? I have a couple other Visual Studio products on my machine and I don't want to completely uninstall everything because some of it takes a long time to set back up. Here are some images to help get an understanding:

**Actual error message:**

[image]

**VC++ folder where lib should be located:**

[image]

**Programs and Features (in case you want to see what other products are installed):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the question "Where Lib should be located ?", i would answer: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC`

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib>pwd
/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/VC/lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib>ls -al msvcrt*.lib
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 1379404 Apr 22  2011 msvcrt.lib
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 1400882 Apr 22  2011 msvcrtd.lib
```

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib>

[image]

Uninstall & Install again ....

Comment: Yes that's where I would also suspect the lib folder should be located. I've uninstalled and reinstalled several times however the folder never gets added back in.

Comment: Have you read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12460307/installation-of-visual-studio-2010-any-edition-installs-only-2-files-in-the-c)  and try to follow steps describe in the 1st answer ?