# VS 2017 not recognizing boost/thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am using VS 2017 and i installed boost/thread NuGet(even reinstalled it a few times). Code shows no error, but when i run it, i get this :

Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.lib'

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: VS2017 supports `std::thread`, which is based on the interface of `bosot::thread`. Especially for new code, I can't imagine using boost::thread anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Boost Nuget package contains only header files. For binaries you will need to add [Boost Thread vc141](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_thread-vc141/). See also [a list of precompiled Boost NuGet packages](https://github.com/sergey-shandar/getboost/blob/master/releases/1.65.1.md#precompiled-libraries). Similar issue [LNK1104 Visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351489/lnk1104-visual-studio-2015/42040883#42040883).

Don't install [Boost Thread Src](https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_thread-src/).