# How to fix LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib' outside c++

Tags: django, visual-c++

I want to install django-admin in my project in virtualenv. After pip install django-admin I receive: `fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'`

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC\\Bin\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
```

> I found solutions to fix this for all projects in c++, but can't find any 
>   solutions for django. Linker is setted and worked.

Tried to create c++ project - works. For other non virtualenv c++ required libraries (ex. numpy) : `Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling C++ Program Causes "Fatal Error LNK1104"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927574/compiling-c-program-causes-fatal-error-lnk1104)

Comment: Yes, this is correct sollution for visual studio c++ linker, not django